# how update table in database with exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I try to update

```
Company_name varchar(40) not null,
Product_unit varchar(20) not null,
Product_quantity int not null,
Product_Barcode varchar(100) null,
Product_expire_date datetime not null,
DurationBeforeWarningsInDays int not null,
DecreasingAmountBeforeWarningsInUnit int not null,
Product_Purchase_price float not null,
Product_Price float not null
```

in product table in my database and take field value from datagridview cells and convert it to its equivalent in the database but i found this exception

> (The multi-part identifier "m.Medicine_contraindications" could not be
>   bound.)

when my program implementation `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
 statement and I do not know the reason for this

```
    private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strconn = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PharmacyV2;integrated security=true;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);
        string mysql = " UPDATE  p set p.Company_name=@C_name,p.Product_unit=@unit,p.Product_quantity=@quantity,p.Product_Barcode=@Barcode,p.DecreasingAmountBeforeWarningsInUnit=@warningAmount,p.Product_expire_date=@EDate,p.DurationBeforeWarningsInDays=@warningTime,p.Product_Purchase_price=@P_price,p.Product_Price=@price ,m.Medicine_contraindications=@M_contr ,m.Medicine_sideEffects=@M_sid from Product p join Medicine m on p.Product_id=m.Product_id where p.Product_name=@name;";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mysql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@C_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@C_name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@unit"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Barcode"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@warningAmount", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@warningAmount"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters["@EDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@warningTime", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@warningTime"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            cmd.Parameters["@P_price"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            cmd.Parameters["@price"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);

            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            arr.Add(TextBox1.Text);

            ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
            arr1.Add(TextBox2.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M_contr",Convert.ToString(arr1));



            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M_sid", Convert.ToString(arr));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Why are you updating on a join?

Comment: because i need to update 2 field from  Medicine table based on Product_name field from Product table

Comment: How about you do a separate update there?

Comment: When you say flied, do you mean field?

Comment: Are you sure you have a column named that?  And if you do, are you sure the datatypes match?

Comment: You cannot be updating **two tables** at once! Your `UPDATE` goes against the `p` table alias (for table `Product`), and you **CANNOT** set values for the `m` table alias (for table `Medicine`) at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to Update two tables with one update statement, you need to break it into `two update statements` and put the two update statement in `one Transaction` , so you can roll back the whole transaction in case of an error, so your data is not left in half done state. you can do something like this

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE p 
          set p.Company_name=@C_name,
              p.Product_unit=@unit,
              p.Product_quantity=@quantity,
              p.Product_Barcode=@Barcode,
              p.DecreasingAmountBeforeWarningsInUnit=@warningAmount,
              p.Product_expire_date=@EDate,
              p.DurationBeforeWarningsInDays=@warningTime,
              p.Product_Purchase_price=@P_price,
              p.Product_Price=@price 

from Product p join Medicine m 
on p.Product_id=m.Product_id 
where p.Product_name=@name;



UPDATE m 
          set m.Medicine_contraindications=@M_contr ,
              m.Medicine_sideEffects=@M_sid 
from Product p join Medicine m 
on p.Product_id=m.Product_id 
where p.Product_name=@name;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SQL Server for years, but I can clearly see the missing information in your query.

You are trying to update table Medicine m but your update contains Product p.

Checkout the syntax here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx